# Unity - UI is in different location in build than in the editor

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity-ui

I have UI of a gun that I keep in the right-bottom of the screen, and properly stays there when i run in edit mode, but for some reason when i build it, it snaps to the left side. I have the UI set to scale with screen size and 1920x1080 as the reference, and all the UI elements are anchored to the bottom right side. Any ideas?

Screenshots:
[In-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YA2H.jpg)
[In-editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Vrv.png)

I have a script that controls weapon bobing and recoil when the gun fires, but I see no reason as to why this would work in the editor but not in the build. It takes the original position of the ui and just builds off of it with hard coded offsets.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it - Just save the position on frame one as the origin, not sure why the aspect ratio would effect it with my settings, but it is what it is

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).